# Saving select option value into database for all rows at once

Tags: php, sql-update

I have this problem of saving the option value into the database. Everything seems to look correctly but when submitted, the value in the database does not change. The form is in a table which retrieve user's submission and consent_id was use to update the option the admin. Hope anyone can spot what I am missing or what it should be written. Thanks.

This is my code:

**manageLeave.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#confirmForm").click(function () {
                $("#statusForm").submit();
            });
        });
    </script>
<body>
                 ...
                    <tr>

                        <td><?php echo $staffName; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $convertDateFrom; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $convertDateTo; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $reason; ?></td>

                        <td>
                            <form method="post" action="doManageLeave.php" id="statusForm" name="statusForm">
                                <input type="hidden" name="consentId" value="<?php echo $consentId; ?>">
                                <select name="leaveStatus" data-native-menu="false">
                                    <option value="" disabled selected style="display: none">Please select one...</option>
                                    <option value="1">Approved</option>
                                    <option value="2">Rejected</option>
                                </select>
                            </form>
                        </td>
                   </tr>
                        <?php
                    }
                    ?>
            </table>
<?php
        }
    }
    ?>
    <input type="button" id="confirmForm" value="Submit" />

 </body>
```

**doManageLeave.php**

```
$getConsentId = $_POST['consentId'];
$leaveStatus = $_POST['leaveStatus'];

$editQuery = "UPDATE consent SET approval_id = '$leaveStatus' WHERE consent_id = $getConsentId";

$successInsert = mysqli_query($link, $editQuery) or die ("Error Query ".  mysqli_error($link));


mysqli_close($link);
```

Comment: `var_dump($_POST)` and check what is getting posted from view file.

Comment: Query is looking fine, there might be a mistake in getting data in $_POST

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju The form only managed to retrieve the last data from the database. The var_dump() returns as array(2) { ["consentId"]=> string(2) "17" ["leaveStatus"]=> string(1) "2" }.

Comment: post values are coming correctly, may be some problem with query, let me check your query

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju The form is within a table, which all request will be shown and the admin may do approve/reject one by one. I'm not sure if this will affect how $_POST retrieves every single consentId

Comment: ya... your query worked fine, try printing the query once and check.

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju Update query does not have a problem, but it only retrieve 1 consent rather than all the consent shown on the table. Should be my select problem which can't retrieve all the consent id

Comment: you want to update all rows at once or single row ??

Comment: Update all rows at once. Sorry if the question is not clear.